# How can I get groovy methods with generics to work with ctags (universal ctags)?

Tags: vim, groovy, tags, ide, ctags

I have tried several ctags configurations, but all of them fail when a method type returns some generic.

```
class Thing {
  List<Thing> doStuff() {
    getSomeList()
  }
}
```

I have a large codebase with these sorts of type checks, and we do sometimes use them with @CompileStatic, so they need to be there.

my ctags configuration:

```
--exclude=.git
--exclude=log
--exclude=*.min.js
--exclude=jquery.*.js
--exclude=jquery-*.js
--exclude=build
--exclude=vendor
--exclude=**/bower_components
--exclude=node_modules

-R

--langdef=groovy
--langmap=groovy:.groovy
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*package[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+)/\1/p,package/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*(private|public)?[ \t]*(abstract|final|static)?[ \t]*class[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/\3/h,class/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*(private|public)?[ \t]*interface[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/\2/i,interface/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*(private|public)?[ \t]*trait[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/\2/t,trait/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*(private|public)?[ \t]*enum[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/\2/e,enum/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*[(abstract|final|static) \t]*((def|void|byte|int|short|long|float|double|boolean|char|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \t]+)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(.*\))[ \t]+/~\3/m,package method/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*public[ \t]+[(abstract|final|static) \t]*((def|void|byte|int|short|long|float|double|boolean|char|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \t]+)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(.*\))[ \t]+/+\3/n,public method/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*protected[ \t]+[(abstract|final|static) \t]*((def|void|byte|int|short|long|float|double|boolean|char|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \t]+)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(.*\))[ \t]+/#\3/b,protected method/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*private[ \t]+[(abstract|final|static) \t]*((def|void|byte|int|short|long|float|double|boolean|char|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \t]+)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(.*\))[ \t]+/-\3/v,private method/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*[(final|static|synchronized) \t]*(def|byte|int|short|long|float|double|boolean|char|[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)([ \t]*[\/]+.*)?/~\2/c,property/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*public[ \t]+[(final|static|synchronized) \t]*(def|byte|int|short|long|float|double|boolean|char|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)([ \t]*[\/]+.*)?/+\2/x,public field/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*protected[ \t]+[(final|static|synchronized) \t]*(def|byte|int|short|long|float|double|boolean|char|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)([ \t]*[\/]+.*)?/#\2/z,protected field/
--regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*private[ \t]+[(final|static|synchronized) \t]*(def|byte|int|short|long|float|double|boolean|char|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)([ \t]*[\/]+.*)?/-\2/l,private field/
```

the resulting tags file:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_MODE   u-ctags /u-ctags or e-ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Universal Ctags Team    //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Universal Ctags /Derived from Exuberant Ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   https://ctags.io/   /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   0.0.0   /157918c6/
Thing   a.groovy    /^class Thing {$/;" h
```

One thing, if I rename my .groovy file to .java, I get the correct tag. So the functionality is in there, somewhere; I just need ctags to use it on groovy files. If my regex was better, maybe I could modify one of these rules, but there seems to be just a little too much going on.

Comment: I was able to get it working by adding <> to the a-zA-Z0-9_ part of the regexes. Is there a better way? Also I realize I might have messed things up by changing the kind letters to all be unique. I did that because I was getting a warning, but now I realize that winds up with duplicate tags :\ Shouldn't be super relevant though.

Comment: Also, I had to remove the tildes from the rules to get them to work with vim. Not sure what they were doing there.

Comment: I was trying to use you `regex-groovy` patterns, but I ran into an error: `Option: --regex-groovy=/^[ \t]*public[ \t]+[(abstract|final|static) \t]*((def|void|byte|int|short|long|float|double|boolean|char|[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \t]+)?([a-zA-Z0-9<>_]+\(.*\))[ \t]+/+\3/n,public method/
ctags: Non-alphanumeric char is used in kind name: 'public method' in "--regex-groovy" option`
Any idea what part of regex may be causing it?

Comment: In the end I found [my .ctags syntax file for Groovy language (exuberant-ctags)](https://gist.github.com/mfwarren/793482) and that is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

as you mentioned that:

> if I rename my .groovy file to .java, I get the correct tag.

it can be only line: `--langmap=java:.groovy`

jsut tried and works for class, method, ... since there is no ';' for a statement in groovy, this method will not parse field, interface function decleration, ...

Comment: I tried this too, but ran into problems with docstrings:
`failed to find match for '(' at line 60`
The line is a part of `Doc = '''\n...\n [link](https://example.com)\n ...\n'''`
I'm not a java guy so I don't know whether java uses different kind of a docstring.
I also ran into [Tell Ctags not to parse content inside comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611912/tell-ctags-not-to-parse-content-inside-comments). But the docstring actually isn't  a comment.

Comment: string in java should be " ... "; or doc string in comment /** */; where your `Doc = '''...'''` is python style.